# How I can validate dates on overlapping

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I faced this problem: when I try to select dates that do not overlap I get an error:
'NoneType' object has no attribute '_autoflush'

this is my code:

```
@app.route('/book/<int:room_id>', methods=['GET'])
def book(room_id):
    room_id = room_id
    dfrom = request.get_json
    dto = request.get_json
    bookings = db.Query(BookData).filter(BookData.date_from>=dfrom, BookData.date_to<=dto, BookData.room_id==room_id).all()
    return bookings'''
```

And this is my model code:

```
 class BookData(db.Model):
 __tablename__ = "Available"

 id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
 user_id = db.Column(db.Integer())

 room_id = db.Column(db.Integer())
 date_from = db.Column(db.Date())
 date_to = db.Column(db.Date())'''
```

Comment: Did you mean `db.session.query(BookData)`?

Comment: Are you sure this query will check for overlap? I'm not that familiar with sql alchemy nor flask, but please check your raw SQL. To me, a date range and a exclusion constraint would be much safer: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRAINT